# Unable to take data from DB and pass with intent

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent

I have request data from MySQL in my First activity

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = "http://myhost/app/get.php?id=" + name_id;

        JSONArray data;
        try {
            resultServer = getJSONUrl(url);
            data = new JSONArray(resultServer);

            MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            HashMap<String, Object> map;

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("id", (String)c.getString("id"));
                map.put("name", (String)c.getString("name"));
                map.put("description", (String)c.getString("description"));

                MyArrList.add(map);
            }                               
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then passing this info to another activity like this

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(act1.this,act2.class);

       newActivity.putExtra("Name", Name);
       newActivity.putExtra("tableDescription", description);
       startActivity(newActivity);
       finish();
```

In next activity I get info like this

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);

    String textDescription, name;
    TextView txtView;

    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    textDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(textDescription+"");
    name = getIntent().getStringExtra("Name");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(name+"");
}
```

So in second activity `Name` is there but `textDescription` is show null and I'm sure that there is text in database in this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem lies in

```
 newActivity.putExtra("tableDescription", description);

 textDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
```

it should be

```
textDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("tableDescription");
```

Comment: No, it is done.. I've changed the `putExtra` intent and all is good now. But I accepted your answer because of problem with mistake in pass and get KEY in intents. I have another problem now but I will post new question since is not related

Answer (score 1):

A simple mistake!

While passing it to newActivity the parameter name in the intent is different then the one you are using to fetch the description :

While Passing :

```
newActivity.putExtra("**tableDescription**", description);
```

and while retrieving user using :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("**description**")
```

The key name should be same in both lines!